# IHS not redirecting the request to WAS

Tags: apache, websphere, httpserver, ibmhttpserver

So, I have installed WAS, and IHS.
I'm able to access the application directly from WAS. But IHS is trying to reply the request and its not using the plugin to reply the request.
I'm able to access the default IHS page, but not to the test application.

To create the IHS, I have done the standard stuff:

1- Install IHS and Plugin
2- Configure the plugin within the IHS
3- Create an unmanaged node on the DMGR
4- Create the webserver instance on the DMGR

I'm just trying to call a sample application called hello (for helloworld)

I see the request on the webservers logs, but they are not being redirected to the WAS.

This is the mention of the plugin on the httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule was_ap22_module /opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so
WebSpherePluginConfig /opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-cfg.xml
```

This is the plugin-cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!--HTTP server plugin config file for the webserver test_Cell.test_webserver_01_unmanagedNode_1.test_webserver_instance1 generated on 20
17.06.25 at 07:37:51 PM CDT-->
<Config ASDisableNagle="false" AcceptAllContent="true" AppServerPortPreference="HostHeader" ChunkedResponse="false" FIPSEnable="false" FailoverToNext="false" HTTPMaxHeaders="
300" IISDisableFlushFlag="false" IISDisableNagle="false" IISPluginPriority="High" IgnoreDNSFailures="false" KillWebServerStartUpOnParseErr="false" MarkBusyDown="false" OS400C
onvertQueryStringToJobCCSID="false" RefreshInterval="60" ResponseChunkSize="64" SSLConsolidate="true" StrictSecurity="false" TrustedProxyEnable="false" VHostMatchingCompat="f
alse">
   <Log LogLevel="Error" Name="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/logs/test_webserver_instance1/http_plugin.log"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnable" Value="true"/>
   <Property Name="ESIMaxCacheSize" Value="1024"/>
   <Property Name="ESIInvalidationMonitor" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnableToPassCookies" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESICacheidFull" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="PostSizeLimit" Value="-1"/>
   <Property Name="PostBufferSize" Value="0"/>
   <Property Name="PluginInstallRoot" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/"/>
   <Property Name="Keyfile" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
   <Property Name="Stashfile" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.sth"/>
   <VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:5060"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:5061"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9061"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9044"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9062"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9081"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9444"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9045"/>
   </VirtualHostGroup>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="false" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="test" PostBufferSize="0" PostSizeLimit="-1"
 RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
      <Server CloneID="1bjgscrk8" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="test_app_01_node_1_test1" ServerIOTimeout="900" W
aitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_01" Port="9080" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_01" Port="9443" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <Server CloneID="1bjgscsei" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="test_app_01_node_1_test2" ServerIOTimeout="900" W
aitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_01" Port="9081" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_01" Port="9444" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <Server CloneID="1bjgscstv" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="test_app_02_node_1_test3" ServerIOTimeout="900" W
aitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_02" Port="9080" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_02" Port="9443" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <Server CloneID="1bjgsctbv" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="test_app_02_node_1_test4" ServerIOTimeout="900" W
aitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_02" Port="9081" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="test_app_02" Port="9444" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/opt/ibm/plugin-ihs-85/test_webserver_instance1/config/test_webserver_instance1/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="test_app_01_node_1_test1"/>
         <Server Name="test_app_01_node_1_test2"/>
         <Server Name="test_app_02_node_1_test3"/>
         <Server Name="test_app_02_node_1_test4"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <UriGroup Name="default_host_test_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/hello/*"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="test" UriGroup="default_host_test_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
   <RequestMetrics armEnabled="false" loggingEnabled="false" rmEnabled="false" traceLevel="HOPS">
      <filters enable="false" type="URI">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="/snoop"/>
         <filterValues enable="false" value="/hitcount"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="SOURCE_IP">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="255.255.255.255"/>
         <filterValues enable="false" value="254.254.254.254"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="JMS">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="destination=aaa"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="WEB_SERVICES">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="wsdlPort=aaa:op=bbb:nameSpace=ccc"/>
      </filters>
   </RequestMetrics>
</Config>
```

Comment: What URL are you accessing? Only /hello/* is being handled by WAS.

Comment: I was accessing the webserver url http://<webserver>:1080/hello
Yes, only hello is being handle by WAS, its the only application I installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally IHS is going to use port 80 to receive communication and rely to the application server.
The port 80 is in the default virtual host. So I added the listening port I'm using (1080) to the default virtual host.